# DrawerLayout, скрыть клавиатуру

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Имеется 2 editText. При открытии DrawerLayout клавиатура не скрывается. Как можно решить данный вопрос?(при нажатии в другое месть можно не скрывать).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрыть клавиатуру при открытии бокового меню можно следующим образом:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

...

mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(YourActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    ...

});
```